# Queston about torrents

Tags: networking, connection, performance, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to make torrent downloads faster?](https://superuser.com/questions/85542/how-to-make-torrent-downloads-faster)
>   [Download rates of torrents through µTorrent and FlashGet are suddenly limited](https://superuser.com/questions/122280/download-rates-of-torrents-through-torrent-and-flashget-are-suddenly-limited)
>   [How to open ports on modem for better torrent performance](https://superuser.com/questions/112791/how-to-open-ports-on-modem-for-better-torrent-performance)

Why do my torrents go at rate 25/30 kb/s and my regular http downloads rate up to 300 kb/s .. is my ISP to blame for this? I meant torrents have like thousand seeders and again its very slow.  How are they blocking torrent speed, can I bypass it?

Results :

> There's no indication that your ISP rate limits all downloads at port 6881.  In our test, a TCP download on a BitTorrent port achieved at least 392 Kbps while a TCP download on a non-BitTorrent port achieved at least 223 Kbps. You can find details here.
>
> There's no indication that your ISP rate limits all uploads at port 6881. In our test, a TCP upload on a BitTorrent port achieved at least 314 Kbps while a TCP upload on a non-BitTorrent port achieved at least 191 Kbps. You can find details here.

Comment: Check out: http://superuser.com/questions/85542/how-to-make-torrent-downloads-faster and http://superuser.com/questions/112791/how-to-open-ports-on-modem-for-better-torrent-performance and http://superuser.com/questions/122280/torrent-download-utorrent-and-flashget-suddenly-got-limited-speed-help-how-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is on a network, and you have access to the router (on home networks, it is often part of the modem), then try find the port forwarding section of your router's settings and set your torrent client's port to forward to your computer.  A few more details here (assuming windows):

1. hit start-> run->type cmd.exe and hit enter.
2. type ipconfig and hit enter.
3. read the IP address (last section after the third . is usually all you care about for this, first three sections are needed for below).
4. close the window.
5. open your torrent client, go to options.
6. search around a bit, you'll find a section that talks about a port to use.  if on clients like vuze, you may need to switch to intermediate or advanced view.  note the port.
7. Open your web browser and go to your router's configuration page (first three sections + a .1 usually.  example: 192.168.1.1).
8. Log in if needed
9. Find the port forwarding section.
10. create a new entry, or enter into an existing empty record the last section of your ip address from #3 and the port number used by the torrent client.
11. save and close.

Answer (score 1):

*removed in favor of https://superuser.com/questions/122280/download-rates-of-torrents-through-torrent-and-flashget-are-suddenly-limited/122339#122339*

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should test if your ISP is actually throttling your torrent trafic.

http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php

If you are being throttled, you might be able to bypass it by enforcing encryption in your torrent software, as this will make it more difficult to detect whether your traffic is actually bittorrent traffic.

Other solutions include the use of a paid VPN or worse, a public proxy.

Comment: that sounds super useful but I'm getting a buggy-looking Security Warning that says "<no associated certificate>".  Is this a Soviet conspiracy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing ports? My ISP occasionally throttles a port (on the rate of every 6 months), and then I just switch to another random port. I run in the 30000-60000 range, and I've nver had issues. You may not need to enable encryption if your ISP uses naive analysis, like mine does.

Comment: @iftrue havent tried to change ports I don't know how

Comment: And you downvoted me because you can't read a help document?

Answer (score 0):

Most ISPs engaging in this behavior now use deep packet inspection which allows them to identify and throttle torrent traffic regardless of the port used.

Comment: @ITGuy24 I don't think my ISP are that thorough..

Answer (score -1):

Randomize the port on every launch, if your router supports uPNP, than it's not a pain at all.  I 2nd iftrue on enabling encryption.

Comment: @matt how do I do that?